# Create docker network with --ingress flag

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I can not clearly understand what `--ingress` flag means when creating docker network in swarm mode.

[Official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/#options) says:

> --ingress | **Create swarm routing-mesh network**

But isn't it enough to create a network with `overlay` driver like this:

```
docker network create -d overlay my-multihost-network
```

[Documentation says](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/) about overlay network:

> an overlay network called **ingress**, which handles control and data traffic related to swarm services. When you create a swarm service and do not connect it to a user-defined overlay network, **it connects to the ingress network by default**.